# How to redirect a login url to a logged in user to a news feed page

Tags: django

I have an app that uses django-user-accounts package to login to the site.

I believe that I have to do this via settings.py file:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'accounts/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'news-feed/'
LOGOUT_URL = ''
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '' # new

def index(request):    
    return render(request, 'feed/index.html',{'page_title': 'HomePage' })




class PostListView(ListView):
    model = PostForNewsFeed
    template_name = 'feed/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5 # add this
    count_hit = True
    slug_field = 'slug'
....        return context



path('', index, name='index'),
path('news-feed/', PostListView.as_view(), name='home2'),
```

How to have the logged in user to redirect to the home url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check your user is authenticated or not

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("news-feed")
    return render(request, 'feed/index.html',{'page_title': 'HomePage' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get settings variable in django views. In addition to @kiran chauhan answer:

```
from django.conf import settings as conf_settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(conf_settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return render(request, 'feed/index.html',{'page_title': 'HomePage' })
```